# Did any country indicate support for Armenia in the ongoing conflict with Azerbaijan? Do they have any potential allies?

Tags: geopolitics, middle-east, azerbaijan, armenia, caucasus

It seems that Turkey, Pakistan and Ukraine have indicated support for Azerbaijan (actually, Pakistan even does not recognize Armenia). Israel also seems to be inclined in favor of Azerbaijan due to good relations and being its main oil importer (reportedly, [there is currently a traffic](https://www.panarmenian.net/rus/news/285759/) of military transport planes between Israel and Azerbaijan). Iran also recently called for the end of Armenian occupation of Azerbaijan's land. Nearby Georgia seems to be in favor of Azerbaijan as well. Libya, a Turkey's client is also in favor of Azerbaijan (and [there are indicators](https://www.panarmenian.net/rus/news/285732/) of charter passenger planes flowing directly from Tripoli to Baku recently).

Russia while being formally in an alliance with Armenia, recently had its relations with Armenia worsened due to a pro-Western and anti-Russian revolution in that country.

I wonder, is there any country in the region or worldwide that indicated or may support Armenia? Is it Saudi Arabia, Syria, France (as they are anti-Turkey) or somebody else?

Comment: It’s from a biased source (obviously), but [Azerbaijan did recently accuse Russia of giving weapons to Armenia.](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-azerbaijan-armenia-russia-idUSKBN25P0L4)

Comment: Macron told Turkey to hold off the warlike rhetoric, if that's indirect support.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Armenia has a very good relationship with Greece. Wikipedia [notes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Armenia%E2%80%93Greece_relations) that Greece was among the first to recognise the Armenian genocide.  There are regular high level contacts with mutual visits of the Greek and Armenian presidents.

Historically, both are Orthodox Christian countries in a long-term dispute with a Muslim neighbour and the alliance between Turkey and Azerbaijan makes a resposive alliance between Greece and Armenia natural (the enemy of my enemy). Armenian officers train in Greek academies.

Cyprus is also an ally, for the same reasons.